# Change column height in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie therefore your help will be much appreciated. 
I'm trying to define column height but none of questions / answers I have found work for me(obviously I am doing something wrong). The idea is to have all information of page within 10 columns, keeping 1 column on each side free-of-infomration(automatically scale for different screen sizes). At the moment language bar is right above banner which doesn't look really nice. What will be correct CSS to increase language row height to 50px keeping text/links vertically aligned in the middle?

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row language">
    <div class="col-sm-11">
    <span class="pull-right"><a href="index_lv.html">LV</a> | <a href="index_ru.html">RU</a> | <a href="index.html">ENG</a>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
<a href="index.html"> <img border="0" src="images/banner.png"></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: It seems, you are using bootstrap. r u? if so could you please add the screen shot or plunker here.

Comment: for screen shot i need at least 10 reputations.
without bootstrap i had it like this:
http://codepen.io/janisdaksa/pen/bNYKRO

with bootstrap it looks like this:
http://codepen.io/janisdaksa/pen/RNjJgQ

Comment: If you have an image, how exactly your page should look like, post the link for it.

Comment: should look like this:
http://i292.photobucket.com/albums/mm40/Janis_Daksa/Untitled_zps282ab61c.jpg
with bootstrap banner goes right after language bar which makes it look too compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row language">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-right">
                <a href="index_lv.html">LV</a> | <a href="index_ru.html">RU</a> | <a href="index.html">ENG</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row banner">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <a href="index.html"><img border="0" src="images/banner.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.language {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now i have another issue- it works in codepen.io just like i would need but when i copy same code to topstyle5- result is same, everything is compressed without required spaces. that makes me wonder if maybe i had already found one or more correct CSS before but for some reason topstyle is not displaying it correctly. what could be the reason for that?